# PyLaTeX Tutorial Generating Error: [WinError 2]

Tags: latex, python-3.5

I am trying to run a [tutorial for PyLaTeX](https://jeltef.github.io/PyLaTeX/current/examples/basic.html#the-code) in Python 3.5. I am using Anaconda / Spyder. When it runs the command "generate_pdf()", [WinError 2] is generated. Below is the code (it is note quoting properly) and the error. It may be easier simply to look at the link.

```
def fill_document(doc):
    with doc.create(Section('A section')):
        doc.append('Some regular text and some ')
        doc.append(italic('italic text. '))

        with doc.create(Subsection('A subsection')):
            doc.append('Also some crazy characters: $&#{}')
             if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Basic document
    doc = Document('basic')
    fill_document(doc)
    doc.generate_pdf(filepath = r'C:\Users\James\Documents\Important Files\Python Scripts\PyLaTeX',clean_tex=False)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-14-0158fa80c4f1>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/James/Documents/Important Files/Python Scripts/PyLaTeX/basic_tutorial.py',
wdir='C:/Users/James/Documents/Important Files/Python
Scripts/PyLaTeX')

  File
"C:\Users\James\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py",
line 714, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File
"C:\Users\James\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py",
line 89, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/James/Documents/Important Files/Python
Scripts/PyLaTeX/basic_tutorial.py", line 21, in <module>
    doc.generate_pdf(filepath = r'C:\Users\James\Documents\Important Files\Python Scripts\PyLaTeX',clean_tex=False)

  File
"C:\Users\James\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pylatex\document.py", line
203, in generate_pdf
    raise(os_error)

  File
"C:\Users\James\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pylatex\document.py", line
157, in generate_pdf
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

  File "C:\Users\James\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 629, in
check_output
    **kwargs).stdout

  File "C:\Users\James\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 696, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:

  File "C:\Users\James\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 950, in
__init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)

  File "C:\Users\James\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1220, in
_execute_child
    startupinfo)

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file
specified
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the exact same problem, but there was a `.log` file present in the directory. So I checked out the log, and the last few lines said that a package called `lastpage.sty` was not found (I'm on Linux), so I just downloaded all the latex packages again using `apt`.

So I think, you should read the log file too, and if there IS something like that, then go to [ctan](http://ctan.org/) (all packages are found there) and install the required package for Windows.

Hope it helped.

Also try putting the `document.generate_tex()` before the `document.generate_pdf(filepath="path/to/file", clean_tex=False)`